# Why Left function returns a run-time error '424'?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below should copy values from a cell and paste its first 10 characters to the same cell in the range. On this line:

```
Sh.Cells(i, 5) = Left(Sh.Cells(i, 5).Value, 10).Copy
```

I get a run-time error '424' (object required). Adding "set" before the line does not work. Does anyone know why is the error triggered here?

```
Sub fixCellsValue()
    Dim wrk As Workbook
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long

    SourceFolder = ThisWorkbook.PATH & "\source"

    If Dir(SourceFolder & "Filename.*") <> "" Then

        Set wrk = Application.Workbooks.Open(SourceFolder & "\Filename.xlsx")
        Set Sh = wrk.Worksheets(1)

        lastrow = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If Len(Sh.Cells(i, 5)) > 10 Then
                Sh.Cells(i, 5) = Left(Sh.Cells(i, 5).Value, 10).Copy
                Sh.Cells(i, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Sh.Cells(i,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: Remove the `.copy` at the end

Comment: and the next line: `Sh.Cells(i, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` remove it also.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thanks for noticing, I've edited. If I remove `.copy` and `.PasteSpecial`, how my code should meet its objective: overwriting cells with the first characters?

Comment: did you try it?  It should.

Comment: @Scott Craner, Now I see it works. copying/pasting not needed here:) Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand how methods and assignment operations work.

> ```
> Sh.Cells(i, 5) = Left(Sh.Cells(i, 5).Value, 10).Copy
> ```

This is assigning the left-hand side (LHS) expression `Sh.Cells(i, 5).Value` (through an implicit default member call) the value returned by the right-hand side (RHS) expression - however the RHS isn't returning anything.

```
Left(Sh.Cells(i, 5).Value, 10)
```

This expression returns a `Variant/String` that is up to 10 characters long. In VBA, a `String` is just a value (like an `Integer` or `Long` is, except it contains text), and values in VBA don't have *member methods*.

So you can't do this:

```
Debug.Print "ABC".Copy
```

Because a member call requires an object - hence, *object required*.

Drop the `.Copy` member call, you'll fix this error.

---

> ```
> Sh.Cells(i, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
> ```

That's technically redundant - the line before it has just done exactly that, by assigning the cell's `Value` directly. But if you want to invoke `Range.Copy`, you can't do it as part of a RHS expression, because `Range.Copy` doesn't return anything - so you would do something like this:

```
Sh.Cells(i, 5).Copy
Sh.Cells(i, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

But then again, that's redundant - you don't need to involve the clipboard here.

Comment: Accepted as the most valuable answer for me. Thank you for this info and your time!

Comment: @Drzemlik always a pleasure! Note that the `Left$` function returns (and intakesl an actual `String` and should be preferred over `Left`, which returns (and intakes) a `Variant` - see *Object Browser* (F2) for more like these; you'll find them under the `VBA.Strings` module. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I saw some mistakes in the code, look:

- `If Dir(SourceFolder & "Filename.*") <> "" Then`: Doesn't have a End If at the end of the code.
- `Sh.Cells(i, 5) = Left(Sh.Cells(i, 5).Value, 10).Copy`: You doesn't need the `.copy` at the end, you're already setting the value.

At the end you should have a code like this:

```
Sub fixCellsValue()
    Dim wrk As Workbook
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long

    SourceFolder = ThisWorkbook.PATH & "\source"

    If Dir(SourceFolder & "Filename.*") <> "" Then

        Set wrk = Application.Workbooks.Open(SourceFolder & "\Filename.xlsx")
        Set Sh = wrk.Worksheets(1)

        lastrow = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If Len(Sh.Cells(i, 5)) > 10 Then
                Sh.Cells(i, 5) = Left(Sh.Cells(i, 5).Value, 10)
                Sh.Cells(i,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: You are currently mistaken about the missing `End If` -- it is there in OP's code (it was put in by an OP-edit a few minutes before you posted this answer).