# 'Format' function returns Run Time Error 424

Tags: excel, vba

Without the format function, the below code gives me the TNPS score correctly, but I'd like the format in percent with two decimal points.

The Format Function is producing error

> Run Time error '424' Object Required.

I referred to a possible duplicate: [Getting error 424](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523166/why-left-function-returns-a-run-time-error-424) yet could not solve it.

```
Public Function tnps(promoter As Integer, passive As Integer, detractor As Integer)
    tnps = (promoter - detractor) / (promoter + passive + detractor)
End Function


Sub main()

Dim pro As Integer
Dim pass As Integer
Dim det As Integer

For i = 2 To 25
    pro = Cells(i, 2).Value
    pass = Cells(i, 3).Value
    det = Cells(i, 4).Value
    Format(Cells(i, 5), "Percent") = tnps(pro, pass, det)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) should be used for a "Expression" and not cells.

You should use [Range.NumberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) like this:

```
Cells(i, 5) = tnps(pro, pass, det)
Range(Cells(i, 5)).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code to

*Format(Cells(i, 5), "Percent") = tnps(pro, pass, det)*

to

*Cells(i, 5) = Format(tnps(pro, pass, det), "0.00%")*

It will work.

Comment: This will put the formatted value in the cell _as a string_, probably not what the OP wants